# How to divide an ul by starting letter following the alphabet

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a list of items which I would like to divide into several lists, each of them starting with a heading following the letters of the alphabet.

So having this as a starting point:

```
<ul>
  <li>A item #1</li>
  <li>A item #2</li>
  <li>A item #3</li>
  <li>B item #4</li>
  <li>B item #5</li>
  <li>B item #6</li>
  <li>C item #7</li>
  <li>C item #8</li>
  <li>C item #9</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
<h2>A</h2>
<ul>
  <li>A item #1</li>
  <li>A item #2</li>
  <li>A item #3</li>
</ul>

<h2>B</h2>
<ul>
  <li>B item #4</li>
  <li>B item #5</li>
  <li>B item #6</li>
</ul>

<h2>C</h2>
<ul>
  <li>C item #7</li>
  <li>C item #8</li>
  <li>C item #9</li>
</ul>
```

I'm equaly interested in a PHP solution or a JS solution.

****** this is the source PHP code, a straight forward WP loop ******

```
<!-- The loop START -->
<?php
global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string."&orderby=title&order=ASC");

if ( have_posts() ) { ?>

  <ul>
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <li>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </li>
        </a>

    <?php } // end while ?>
  </ul>

<?php } // end if
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
<!-- The loop END -->
```

Comment: well are you building it dynamically in PHP? If yes, than that is where it should be done.

Comment: What's the original data doing before it's on the DOM? Can you just change the display there? Either way you should ideally be able to write a method to group the list items (or their source data) by first letter, and then spit out one `<ul>` block each

Comment: @epascarello the `ul` is buing built inside the wordpress loop, so yes, I could potentially target the matter there in PHP, thats one of the solutions I'm interested in finding out

Comment: Not difficult to do with javascript but doing it at source makes more sense

Comment: Can you post the code which you have attempted? Is it not working in some way? "Give me the codez" style questions are generally frowned upon here.

Comment: What does the data in PHP look like? (In addition to @MonkeyZeus's comment above)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I havent attempted this yet, I was looking to gather other people's thoughts on what would be the right approach as I wasnt sure to do it with PHP or JS

Comment: @SunnyPatel just added my PHP, its a WP loop

Comment: Good luck with that, this isn't a discussion forum. The right approach is to do this in PHP so that you do not have delayed DOM manipulation which changes your list's display shortly after the page has loaded. I highly recommend trying something, anything....

Comment: Note that wrapping a `<li>` in `<a>` is invalid html. Create an array of arrays using the first letter of each title as key and posts for values then loop over that php array to produce expected results

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
var headings = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

var $list = $('#list').detach();
$.each(headings.split(''), function() {
  var letter = this;
  var found = $list.find("li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(letter) === 0;
  });
  if (found.length > 0) {
    $('body').append('<h2>' + letter + '</h2>');
    $('body').append($('<ul/>').append(found));
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var headings = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

var $list = $('#list').detach();
$.each(headings.split(''), function() {
  var letter = this;
  var found = $list.find("li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(letter) === 0;
  });
  if (found.length > 0) {
    $('body').append('<h2>' + letter + '</h2>');
    $('body').append($('<ul/>').append(found));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>A item #1</li>
  <li>A item #2</li>
  <li>A item #3</li>
  <li>B item #4</li>
  <li>B item #5</li>
  <li>B item #6</li>
  <li>C item #7</li>
  <li>C item #8</li>
  <li>C item #9</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps and solves your problems

Comment: As far as a JS solution goes this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you should be able to replace your WP code with the following:

```
$letter = "";
while ( have_posts() ) {
  $title = get_the_title();
  if ($letter !== $title[0]) { //Check first letter against previous first letter
    if ($letter !== "") { // Close previous <ul> if not the first time in loop ?>
      </ul> <?php
    } ?>

    <h2><?= $title[0] ?></h2>
    <ul> <?php
  }
    the_post(); ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?= $title ?>
      </a>
    </li> <?php
  $letter = $title[0];
} // end while
if ($letter !== "") { //If there were any posts, need to close last <ul> ?>
  </ul> <?php
}
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
<!-- The loop END -->
```

It basically changes up the loop to check the first letter matching with previous post's first letter, and starts a new `<ul>` in those scenarios with a final closing `</ul>`.

**Bonus:** The `<a>` tags are inside the `<li>` tags for more sensible HTML

**Edit:** Missing few php tags and convert `the_title()` to `get_the_title()` since the former seems to echo the result instead of returning it.

Comment: your code is slightly off, like some php tags are not closing, you are using the_title() when it should be get_the_title() and other minor  issues, but your apporach is great and I was able to adapt your solution to work as expected. Would love to mark this answer as correct but would need to edit it first

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, I'll loop on each `<li>` and then push it to the respective `<ul>`.

```js
$(function () {
  // Loop.
  $("ul li").each(function () {
    var init = $(this).text().substr(0, 1);
    // If the element doesn't exist yet, create one.
    if ($("ul." + init).length == 0)
      $("ul").last().after('<ul class="' + init + '"></ul>');
    // Append it in the respective LI.
    $("ul." + init).append($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>A item #1</li>
  <li>A item #2</li>
  <li>A item #3</li>
  <li>B item #4</li>
  <li>B item #5</li>
  <li>B item #6</li>
  <li>C item #7</li>
  <li>C item #8</li>
  <li>C item #9</li>
</ul>
```